# Dagger2 Circular Dependency Error

Tags: dagger-2

I am using dagger2 2.16 version for dependency injection inside mine android project. I examine a lot of examples, and although I do not have a similar approach I get the error of "circular dependency".
Mine source code;
**AppComponent.kt**

```
@Singleton
@Component(
        modules = [
            AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
            AppModule::class,
            ActivityBuilderModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: App)
}
```

**App.kt**

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        AppInjector.init(this)
        initOneSignal()
    }

    private fun initOneSignal() = OneSignal.startInit(this).setNotificationOpenedHandler(CustomNotificationOpenedHandler()).inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification).init()


    override fun activityInjector() = dispatchingAndroidInjector
}
```

**ActivityBuilderModule.kt**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilderModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun contributeSplashActivity(): SplashActivity
}
```

**AppModule.kt**

```
@Module(includes = [(ViewModelModule::class)])
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideContext(app: Application): Context = app.applicationContext;

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideApiService(client: OkHttpClient): ApiService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(ApiService::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        return interceptor
    }
}
```

If I remove the ActivityBuilderModule from the AppComponent, the project is compiled without problems. But if you add to the modules section, the project gives the error below.

> error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError]
>   dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this
>   interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check
>   for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In App.kt you need to initialize component with the application context. the line

```
AppInjector.init(this)
```

should be inside the Activity i.e. splashActivity in which you're going to inject the dependencies.

Comment: Hi. as you say, I initialize the component here. Here is AppInjector source code
[link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/AppInjector.kt)

Comment: what are you trying to say? @AhmetBurakDemirkoparan

Comment: I am initialize the dagger component in AppInjector as you said. The project is not compiled when I contribute activity.

Comment: did you remove that line AppInjector.init(this) from App.kt? if you've removed that what's the error showing right now?

Comment: The same error still occurs when I rebuild the project despite the deletion of the line.

Comment: did you added that line inside splashActivity?

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned error message might also appear, because kotlin stdlib is not declared as dependency. So adding e.g. `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.60")` in your build.gradle(.kts) file might also help.